# Is Angular ComponentA destroyed when navigating away to ComponentB?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose `ComponentA` is displayed in the `<RouterOutlet>` and the user navigates such that `ComponentB` is displayed in the same `<RouterOutlet`>.  Is the `ComponentA` instance then destroyed such that a new instance of `ComponentA` is created if the user navigates back to `ComponentA` again?

If `ComponentA` implements `OnInit` this would result in `ComponentA.onInit()` being called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you are right. if any component is loaded by angular route inside 'RouterOutlet' then when another component gets loaded, the current component gets destroyed after calling it's last callback method ngOnDestroy().

Answer (score 1):

If componentA is replaced by another component, the `ngOnDestroy()` method of componentA is called. But the stuff created by componentA is not destroyed automatically. If you want to clean up stuff created by componentA, you have to do it yourself by writing code inside `ngOnDestroy()` method of componentA.

For example, if you have subscribed some endless observables in `ngOnInit()`, you need to unsubscribe it in `ngOnDestroy()`, otherwise the subscription will be active even after another component has replaced componentA.